# C# Deserialising Json data array with missing column names

Tags: c#, json

I have the following Json Data:

```
{"status": "ok", 
 "data": [
     {"2016-12-12 02:00:00": 29.6}, 
     {"2016-12-12 02:30:00": 29.4}, 
     {"2016-12-12 03:00:00": 28.9}, 
     ...... many more records 
]}
```

In and ideal world, the data would include column/field names:

```
{"status": "ok", 
 "data": [
     {"ts": "2016-12-12 02:00:00", "temp": 29.6}, 
     {"ts": "2016-12-12 02:30:00", "temp": 29.4}, 
]}
```

However the column names are missing.  I would like to know how to retrieve the data into the following Class Structure:

```
#region JSON Class
public class telemetryData
{
    public string ts { get; set; }
    public double temp { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public List<telemetryData> data { get; set; }
}
#endregion
```

I am deserialising the data using the following:

```
JavaScriptSerializer sr = new JavaScriptSerializer();
jsonResponse = sr.Deserialize<RootObject>(jsonString);

foreach (var item in jsonResponse.data)
{
    OutputMoistureBuffer.AddRow();
    OutputMoistureBuffer.ts = item.ts;
    OutputMoistureBuffer.temp = item.temp;
}
```

This code is being used in an SQL Server 2008 R2 SSIS Package, using VS2008 C#.  I am unable to 'step through' and debug the code in a Script component, and as such I am unable to get a accurate error message as to why I am unable to get it to work.

Any assistance on the correct formatting of my JSON Class would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) package for json deserialization. It allows to write custom converters

```
public class TelemetryDataConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(telemetryData);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader,
        Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        var property = (JProperty)obj.First;

        return new telemetryData {
            ts = property.Name,
            temp = property.Value.Value<double>()
        };
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer,
       object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then you can either put custom converter attribute to your class, or pass converter to deserializer:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(TelemetryDataConverter))]
public class telemetryData
{
    public string ts { get; set; }
    public double temp { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialization will look like:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

NOTE: Consider to parse date strings into DateTime objects. Also consider to use PascalCase naming for classes and properties.

Comment: Thanks for your help Sergey, however I while the code buids, I get an new error: Package Validation Error

Error at Data Flow Task [Script Component [184]]: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.CannotCreateUserComponentException: Cannot create user component class. Make sure there is one class marked with SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute in your script.
Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: "component "Script Component" (184)" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".    This error only occurs after I reference the Newtonsoft.Json.DLL. If I remove it, it works.

Comment: This error has only started occurring after I installed and referenced Newtonsoft.Json.Dll, and the corresponding code.  If I remove it, the code runs again (even if it is not giving me the data I want).  The code also works perfectly in a later version of Visual studio.